# Appending the -Xss64m flag in the config.ini file doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-size

I need to change the default Stack size of my Java projects in Eclipse in order not to do it manually by appending the -XssNUMm (e.g. -Xss64m) flag to the VM in every project I create, which can be many per day.

I read that by appending the flag in the config.ini file it should change the default values but it is not working.

I added the -Xss64m flag and tried to run a program and get the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError ". If I put the flag manually in the runAs or debugAs configurations it works flawlessly.

I'm using Windows 7, and Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs'.

Select the JRE you are using and click 'Edit...'.

Enter your default -Xss setting in the 'Default VM arguments' field.